# IAM Desktop, connect client application, to a gcp vm, can't serve static files with size bigger than1.6MB

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-platform, virtual-machine, limit, cvat

[image]

We are trying to connect to the CVAT web ui.

We followed the tutorial from https://opencv.github.io/cvat/docs/administration/basics/installation/, applied a docker compose... and once the server is running via the container on the VM, we wanted to connect to the UI.

To do so, we right clicked on the VM, and in connect client application, chose port 8080... By this port forwarding, we tried accessing localhost:43250 (A random port of the forwarding...), but it seems to take forever. When we do F12, we get the attached image above.

Is there a way to change a property on the Linux VM machine, of the GCP? Perhaps there is some limit on how big a static js file can be. Is it a permission problem of the GCP itself that we need to grant access?

Thanks in advance,

Jeff

We tried to connect, to CVAT ui, by building a docker, on a GCP VM.

We expected to be able to connect to the UI itself... but it doesn't connect, since there seems to be some limit of exactly 1.6MB, on the static served js files